Evaluation of an integral with result as special functions and matching Mathematica's results
This question is about calculating the integral
\begin{equation}
I = \int_\varepsilon^\infty v^{\frac m2} (v-\varepsilon)^{\frac k2+j-1} \exp{\left(-\frac{v}{2\varsigma}\right)}dv
\end{equation}
where $m,j>=0,k>0$ are integers and $\varepsilon,\varsigma$ are positive-valued reals.
I get
\begin{equation}
\frac{\Gamma \left(j+\frac{k}{2}\right) {\varepsilon}^{j+\frac{k}{2}+m+\frac{1}{2}} \Gamma \left(-j-m-\frac{k}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right) {}_1F_1\left(m+\frac{3}{2};j+\frac{k}{2}+m+\frac{3}{2};-\frac{{\varepsilon}}{2{\varsigma}}\right)}{\Gamma \left(-m-\frac{1}{2}\right)}+2^{j+\frac{k}{2}+m+\frac{1}{2}} {\varsigma}^{j+\frac{k}{2}+m+\frac{1}{2}} \Gamma \left(j+\frac{k}{2}+m+\frac{1}{2}\right){}_1F_1\left(-j-\frac{k}{2}+1;-j-m-\frac{k}{2}+\frac{1}{2};-\frac{{\varepsilon}}{2 {\varsigma}}\right)
\end{equation}
I can show this result using results from Abramowitz and Stegun, and Gradshtein and Ryzhik.
Indeed, Mathematica 13.1 gives the same/similar results.
Integrate[
 u^(m + 1/2)*Exp[-u/(2*rho)]*(u - eps)^(j + k/2 - 1) , {u, eps, 
  Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> 
  m >= 0  && j >= 0 && k > 0 && eps > 0 && rho > 0 && 
   Element[eps && rho, Reals] && Element[ m && j && k, Integers] ]

gives the result:
2^(1/2+j+k/2+m) rho^(1/2+j+k/2+m) Gamma[1/2+j+k/2+m] Hypergeometric1F1[1-j-k/2,1/2-j-k/2-m,-(eps/(2 rho))]+(1/Gamma[-(1/2)-m])eps^(1/2+j+k/2+m) Gamma[j+k/2] Gamma[-(1/2)-j-k/2-m] Hypergeometric1F1[3/2+m,3/2+j+k/2+m,-(eps/(2 rho))]

What I can not understand is how to evaluate the above integral for odd $k$. It appears to me that the first term in either my derivation or the Mathematica expression is infinite because of the presence of the $\Gamma(\cdot)$ function evaluated at a negative integer.
Any suggestions on how to actually evaluate this?

Evaluate the expression near k (for odd k), i.e. $k_{\text{act}}=k+10^{-30}$.
See also MSE_Q4975393

Thank you! May I try and understand what the reductions are that may cause this approach to work?

The singularities at odd k values are removable with power series expansion at these points.
